# Is call xmlParserInit() from lambda function called to initialize static variable a bad idea?

Tags: c++, c++17, libxml2

These are constrains:

1. I need use libxml2 SAX interface in multithreaded environment
2. Code is statically linked
3. I don't have control on threads, so I don't have a direct access to main thread from which `xmlParserInit()` should be called in accordance to documentation

I came up with the following idea

```
// SAXClient.cpp

const static bool PARSER_INITIALIZED = ()[] {
    xmlParserInit();
    return true;
}();
```

This code initializes the variable by the lambda called even prior to main() call in the main thread as it is required.

Do I miss some pitfall here?

Comment: [Deferred_dynamic_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Deferred_dynamic_initialization) can happen.

Comment: Why not use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `xmlInitParser`, it can be called multiple times and is thread-safe. Just call it before you start using libxml2.

In general, I'd recommend to call `xmlInitParser` from the main thread first. But this shouldn't be strictly necessary.